# Singleton class accessed from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a scenario where I have to connect to virtual center and get data. I have implemented a singleton class so that two threads cannot access the VC at the same time, as it has give concurrent access issue. My code is as follows:

```
public class Connector {    
private static Connector instance ;    
private Connector(String urlStr, String username, String password) {
    connect(urlStr, username, password);
}    
public static synchronized Connector getInstance(String urlStr, String username, String password) {
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new Connector(urlStr,username,password);
        System.out.println("creating instance");
    }
    return instance ;
}   
public void connect(String urlStr, String username, String password) {
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        //code to connect to VC
        }

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        connectException = e;
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
    }
}


public void disconnect() throws RuntimeFault, RemoteException {
    //code for disconnect
    }
}
```

}

I called this from another class in the following way:

```
Connector c = Connector.getInstance(dburl, dbuser, dbpass);
c.connect(dburl, dbuser, dbpass);
//code for getting data
c.disconnect();
```

Now if I have 2 simultaneous requests to get data from viruatal center, one of them fails saying "session is not authenticated". 
Can you help we with a better way to deal with the issue. 
And as the same instance is used always, how can we differentiate if its a different Virtual Center.

Comment: To put it another way - just what @RomanC says.

Comment: Read : https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence

1. connect
2. do stuff
3. disconnect

is not atomic which means it is possible that

1. Thread 1 connects
2. Thread 2 connects
3. Thread 1 does stuff
4. Thread 1 disconnects
5. Thread 2 tries to do stuff and fails.

---

Structure your class so that clients cannot fail to connect, fail to disconnect, or interleave operations with another.

Your API could allow code that wants to use a connection to pass in an object that uses a connection while it is connected, and returns a result of using that connection:

```
 public interface ConnectionTask<T> {
   public T useConnection(Connection c);
 }
```

and then instead of `getInstance` write a `useConnection` that does

```
 public synchronized <T> T useConnection(ConnectTask<T> c) {
   connect();
   try {
     return c.useConnection(this);
   } finally {
     disconnect();
   }
 }
```

and make `connect` and `disconnect` `private` so that clients cannot misuse them.

Answer (score 0):

You are only retaining exclusive access to the connection in the first method.

I suggest you add a `Lock` like `ReentrantLock` which you lock in the first method and unlock when you release the connection.

Another approach is to use a visitor pattern which may be safer.

```
interface UsesConnector {
    public void useConnector(Connector connector);
}

public class Connector {
    private static final Connector connector = new Connector();

    public static synchronized void useConnector(String urlStr, String username, String password, UsesConnector usesConnector) {
         connector.connect(urlStr, username, password);
         try {
             usesConnector.useConnector(connector);
         } finally {
             connector.disconnect();
         }
    }
}
```